# Existence of co-variables

Tags: covariance

In a study, there are 3 independent variables (A, B, C). I want to manipulate only (A, B).
The idea of not manipulating variable C is for it not to interfere with the other two manipulated variables A, B. In this way, the researcher is confident that only A or/and B are causing an effect on the dependent variable.

(i) I am not sure how to describe the above in statistical language. How should I best put it?

(ii) In this case, variable C is not regarded as a co-variate, as it is kept constant. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: From what I can tell, this sounds like an appropriate set up for a statistical experiment. I think your results will only be generalizable to populations with the same C variable (for example if C was male, then your results would only be applicable to males).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you should refer to `C` as a variable if all your observations are selected to be identical with respect to `C`. I would refer to `C` as a *selection criterion* in this case.

If `C` is not identical across all your observations, then there are two alternatives to consider:

- If you're excluding observations with values/levels of `C` that are not equal to a constant you've chosen, you are applying an *exclusion criterion* to create a *subset* of your dataset.
- If you're simply not manipulating `C`, but are controlling for it in your analyses such that it is held constant statistically when testing for effects of `A` or `B`, then `C` is in fact a *covariate* after all.